How to check if type (not object) has a specific property?
I am working with a generated complex type that is rather big. I need to check if certain properties exists on the type with create a variable and initializing all its properties to default/null values, since that would be too much work.
Is there a way to check if properties exists directly on type without instantiating them or creating a variable with all its properties and checking against it?
ex:
Assuming I have the following
    export type Mutations {
        upsertItem: {},
        upsertItemMany: {},
        removeItem: {},
        removeItemMany: {},
        upsertCustomer: {},
        upsertCustomerMany: {},
        removeCustomer: {},
        removeCustomerMany: {},
        ... (1000+ more properties exist)
    }

I tried to do something like:
    var mutations: Mutations;
    Object.hasOwn(mutations, 'upsertItem');

But all I get is the following error:
"Cannot convert undefined or null to object"
and if I try to initialize the variable like
    let mutations: Mutation = {};

I get an error that I need to specify all its properties which defeats the purpose.
I am guessing this can be solved using reflections but I don't know how.

What do you need to do with this information? You've shown a run-time check (types are only exist at compile-time) and you mentioned reflection (which doesn't exist for TS because it requires runtime support for types). Right now the question doesn't make sense, since there is not much you can do with a property existence check. You can't make branching run-time decisions based on that. You can only write code that compiles correctly. If you explain what your goal is, then we can probably give you more meaningful information how to reach it.

Welcome to SO! If you only need to discover this while writing code, you could write declare let mutations: Mutation; and then mutations.upsertItem and see if it complains or not. Does that work for you? If you need it at runtime then please [edit] to explain why, preferably describing the underlying use case. Right now this looks very much like an XY problem where you're asking how to do something that won't actually help you.

The short answer is, you cannot.
A good thing to remember about Typescript is that is is only a compile-time thing. None of the typescript stuff will be present at runtime. This includes the type construct.
What you are trying, is to perform a runtime check but that will not be possible as the code simply does not know anything related to typescript after it is compiled and when it runs. It's just plain javascript

Thank you for the answer @hassan-naqvi,
basically I just need to know if a certain type has a certain property. I will be working with many types and each has 1000+ properties.
Isn't there a way, to convert the type to string and just parse the string?
it just seems strange that I cannot convert the type to an object and enumerate the properties on it....

@buggyCode As I said, you have no remanants of the type at runtime. So you cannot convert it to anything in any way. The way I see to achieve what you want is to change the generation code to create objects instead of types if you have control over it. Or maybe you can tell what you want to do after you ennumerate the property and there is some other way to achieve the end goal
